# How to find upper bound of a probability?

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

We roll a fair die 50 times and count the number of 2’s. Give an upper bound for the probability that the count of 2’s stays below 7.
How can I approach this problem?

Comment: $1$ is a good upper bound.

Comment: I did not understand. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Well, you could just directly calculate the probability that the number of successes is less than 7. Or, you could just say that this probability (like all probabilities) are equal or less than 1 (sortof "trolling answer"). This is maybe what Tavish was implying. Or, a third option (and it's probably what is sought here) is to take the expression for $P(\text{less than 7 successes})$ and make some approximations so that it's easier to calculate. But the approximation should be larger than the exact expression. Do you know how to calculate the probability?

Comment: I know that if I roll a dice, the prob of getting 2 is 1/6. So, if I roll it 50 times, the sum of prob is 50*1/6. But how can I create an upper bound?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_i, i=1,2..50$ be a set of independent random variables with success probability $1/6$ (1 if 2 comes). Define $S = \sum_{i = 1}^{50}X_i$. You want to bound, $P(S \leq 7)$. One thing you can do is using [Chebyshev's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) or the more tight [Chernoff Bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound). The idea is that, $P(S \leq a) = P(e^{-tS } \geq e^{-ta}) \leq\frac{ E[e^{-tS}]}{e^{-ta}}, t > 0$ by Markov's inequality. You then simply minimize over the parameter t by differentiating the bound and equation to 0. This employs the additive structure of your problem since exponentiation acts nicely to addition. In Chebyshev's inequality, you only look at the second moment and assume nothing about the others, while in Chernoff's bound you are effectively looking at higher moments so you will get tighter bounds.

Comment: The result that you can directly use if you can't do it yourself is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Multiplicative_form_(relative_error)).

Comment: Thanks a lot man. If I want to use markov inequality, I need to calculate E(x). 
E(x)= 50*2*1/6. 
Is the calculation right?

Comment: If X stands for the number of 2's it is 50 / 6. That 2 shouldn't be there.

Comment: I need to calculate P(X<7) but markov inequality gives us P(X>=7).
So if I do 1-P(X>=7) that gives me P(X<7).
P(X=>7) <= E(X)/7. 
So here, E(X)/7= 50/(6*7) = 50/42.
So P(X<7)= 1-50/42 . 
Is the calculation right? Or I am missing something? 
Again thanks for the help.